# Calling a DB2 Stored Procedure in a DB2 function

Tags: db2

Can we call a DB2 Stored procedure from a DB2 function. Also my stored procedure has parameters and it returns a table, so I have to pass these parameters to the stored procedure through the function only. 
Can anyone let me know if its possible.

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.  Nothing in the [documentation](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246503.pdf) is sticking out to me that says User Defined Functions are prevented from, or shouldn't be calling a Stored Procedure.

It seems like the easy answer would be to try it out by creating a small test scenario.  Without knowing why you're looking to do this, I can't offer much more advice since I've never done it personally.  However another option, if you can't get the UDF to process result sets from a stored procedure call is to have the UDF call a program (or service program procedure) and have that object call the stored procedure and return whatever info you need the UDF to return.